# Effects of multiple non-independent treatments

Tags: mixed-model, inference, modeling, linear, observational-study

I need to run an analysis of efficiency of automated recommendations for call-centre agents on how to handle  customer support tickets. It works like that:

1. A ticket get 0, 1 or more recommendations based on the rules that use ticket's or customer's attributes as input.
2. Different recommendations may be correlated to various  extent, both due to overlapping  rules and because  customer's and ticket's attributes may be not independent.
3. Agent may or may not "engage" with each recommendation (click on them, read them etc). It's not random in general - some agents may be more prone to ignore recommendations.
4. Sometimes a recommendation is "triggered" (i.e. its rule is satisfied), but not created, to make this ticket a part of "control group".
5. Agents are assigned to tickets not randomly - some of them work on specific types of tickets, so recommendations subsets and agents that see them are not independent too.

We need to measure the effect of each recommendation type on a continuous outcome variable (some real positive number).

What kind of model/observational study design would be appropriate here? Ideally, I think, we'd compare the outcome only between groups of tickets where exactly the same subset of recommendations was triggered, but we don't have enough data points with various combinations of recommendations "used"/"not used" (i. e. when it's a part of control group, or not "engaged" with by agent).

Is it possible to use different groups of tickets to estimate individual effects (e. g. use tickets with recos A, A+B, A+C together to estimate effect of A)?

Also, how to take into account that different groups of agents work on different types of tickets (but not necessarily exclusively)? Is it something that linear mixed models can help with?